# all items in listview assign to checked in java

Tags: java, if-statement

I have list view in android with multiple check option,
when i checked some items, it execute the action for all items,

```
@Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
           int cntChoice = lv.getCount();
           String checkedd = "";

           String unchecked = "";
            SparseBooleanArray checked = lv.getCheckedItemPositions();
            ArrayList<String> selectedItems = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (int i = 0; i < cntChoice; i++) {


                    if(checked.get(i) == true)
                    {
                        checkedd = lv.getItemAtPosition(i).toString() ;
                        Pushbots.sharedInstance().tag(checkedd);
                    }
                    else  if(checked.get(i) == false)
                    {
                        unchecked= lv.getItemAtPosition(i).toString() ;

                    }
```

even some items i did not checked, but it assign it as checked and execute this code
  Pushbots.sharedInstance().tag(checkedd);

:

this my all code :_

```
String list[]={"decision","data","math","ic3"};
private String my_sel_items;
ArrayAdapter<String> ard;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    sharedInstance().init(this);
    my_sel_items = new String();

    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.exp_list);
    ard = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, list);
    lv.setAdapter(ard);

    lv.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
  btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


       @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
           int cntChoice = lv.getCount();
           String checkedd = "";

           String unchecked = "";
            SparseBooleanArray checked = lv.getCheckedItemPositions();
            ArrayList<String> selectedItems = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (int i = 0; i < cntChoice; i++) {


                    if(checked.get(i) == true)
                    {
                        checkedd = lv.getItemAtPosition(i).toString() ;
                        Pushbots.sharedInstance().tag(checkedd);
                    }
                    else  if(checked.get(i) == false)
                    {
                        unchecked= lv.getItemAtPosition(i).toString() ;

                    }}}
```

Comment: This is not a android question is is a java question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be a beginner in regards to java with this kind of question. In order to best understand what is the problem here you should read the documentation of how a switch works.

Try reading this:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html

Learn the use of what `break` and `case` keyword mean.

As a hint, all lines underneath case statement will be executed, unless a break is encountered. Also you **CAN** have N case statements aggregated.

Comment: I add break to the last case to execute all, but does not work,, i think the problem in statement----Pushbots.sharedInstance().setAlias

Comment: Also it is your switch statement that has the problem. If you read the documentation you'll know what to do

Comment: i changed to this
 public void onClick(View arg0) {
 SparseBooleanArray checked = lv.getCheckedItemPositions();
 ArrayList<String> selectedItems = new ArrayList<String>();
  for (int i = 0; i < checked.size(); i++) {
                    int position = checked.keyAt(i);
 if (checked.valueAt(i)){
  selectedItems.add(ard.getItem(position));}
                    
                    
            String[] outputStrArr = new String[selectedItems.size()];
  outputStrArr[i] = selectedItems.get(i);
 Pushbots.sharedInstance().tag(outputStrArr[i]);

but it set tag to all even not selected one